# reading FILE * into class

Tags: c, file, class

I am attempting to read an entry in a text file and place it into a class. The text file is structured like this:

```
ABCD
3.00
2
6.00
-
```

into a class:

```
typedef struct item
{
    char        *name;
    double      uprc;
    double      cost;
    int         qty;
} item;
```

"ABCD" is name, 3.00 is `uprc`, 2 is `qty` and 6.00 is `cost`.

How can I implement this? So far, I have:

```
void read()
{
    item i;
    FILE *f = fopen(PATH, "r");
    char *buf;
    int c, nl_ct = 0;
    while((c = getch(f)) != EOF){
        putchar(c);
        if(c == '\n'){
            nl_ct++;
            switch(nl_ct){
            case 1:
                {
                    char *buf;
                    while(fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), f))

                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, I don't know what to do in the innermost `while` loop. Also, this code looks incorrect.

How can I code this?

Comment: use `ifstream` if it's C++

Comment: I prefer to use `FILE *`, it's easier to understand

Comment: sorry, it's a weak excuse for someone who asks how to stack while-loops and getch()/fgets() calls in order to read four lines from a text file. don't you even wanna try?

Comment: "Teach me how to do this" is not really an appropriate question for SO. If you have specific questions once you've learned the basics from another source, people are generally willing to help.

Comment: This doesn't look like C++, other than the all-public `class` emulating a C `struct`.  If you have a C programming question (regarding `FILE*`, for instance) you'll get a more capable audience using the **C** tag instead of **C++**.

Comment: @DrewDormann actually the class has member functions, but I didn't post it because they are irrelevant.

Comment: _"I prefer to use FILE *, it's easier to understand"_ - and easier to introduce bugs, harder to maintain, requires a lot of extra effort to use with C++ constructs. Yeah, spectacular choice.

Comment: `I prefer to use FILE *, it's easier to understand –`  And I guess `char *` is easier to "understand" than using  the very simple `std::string`? Am I right? Seriously, just because something is easier to type doesn't make it easier to use.

Comment: It's not "unclear" what is being asked, it is clear to me that OP is having trouble parsing a file, and he has posted a sample of what he has tried. Why the close votes?

Comment: @dreamlax it's an unclear "hold" reason, I agree.  OP seemed to get pinched by the question's premise _"help me write C code that only a C++ compiler can build"_.  (He ruled out `ifstream` long before your otherwise good answer was posted)

Comment: The Stack Overflow close reasons are absolutely terrible.  I came from the review queue to this question and the reason of "unclear" is not even close.

Comment: That's on me, at least partially.  The "Off topic because..." reason allows a fill-in reason.  I could have typed a logical reason there, but I was lazy and didn't.  That said, more than an hour ago I voted to reopen this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is made much simpler if you just use the tools provided by C++.

Given:

```
class item
{
public:
    std::string name;
    double uprc;
    double cost;
    int qty;
};
```

You can just do (after including `<string>`, `<fstream>` and `<iostream>`):

```
std::ifstream input(PATH);
item i;

std::getline(input, i.name); 
input >> i.uprc;
input >> i.qty;
input >> i.cost;
```

The reason to use `std::getline` is so that the entire line is read, if you do just `input >> i.name;` then it will only read up until the first whitespace character, so it won't work for names with spaces.

Alternatively, you can provide your own `operator>>` so that you can do just `input >> i;`. Note also that there is no error checking done here, so you'll need to add that yourself.

Answer (score 2):

1) Your bigger problem is that you don't seem to be allocating any space for "*buff" (assuming you ever want to read more than 1 character at a time), or for "*name".  *YOU MUST DO THIS*.  Either malloc(), or fixed-size arrays.

2) I agree - this definitely looks like C.  Why not just use a "struct" (instead of "class" with everything "public:") and be done with it?

3) However, if you are using C++ - I'd definitely urge you to consider ifstream.

4) More importantly, you should also consider using C++ "string" instead of character arrays.

IMHO...